# How do I "Free look"?

Tags: call-of-duty-mobile

In PUBG mobile, the "Free look" button (indicated by the eye icon) lets you look around without changing the direction your character is moving in.

[image]

I can't find/figure out similar functionality in CoD Mobile.

If I customize my BR controls in CoD, I see I have access to the same eye icon (screenshot below). However, when I'm actually playing the game, the eye icon is not visible and I don't have the ability to "look around".

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free look is only available when in TPP, not FPP.

The only time you can free look when in FPP is when you're parachuting.

Comment: It is also available while riding any vehicle, snowboarding, while wing suit is activated.